# Как вынуть значения, simplehtmldom

Tags: php

Написал выборку:

```
$ret = $html->find('.firminfo h1 abbr'); 
    print_r($ret);
```

Получился результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => simple_html_dom_node Object
        (
            [nodetype] => 1
            [tag] => abbr
            [attr] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Значение поля
                )

            [children] => Array
                (
                )

            [nodes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => simple_html_dom_node Object
                        (
                            [nodetype] => 3
                            [tag] => text
                            [attr] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [children] => Array
```

Так вот как мне вынуть значение из самого начала,  вот тут `[attr] [title]` => Значение поля?

Comment: Хотел вот так, но не получилось: echo $ret->title . '<br>';

Answer (score 2):

Как подсказывает `print_r`, $ret является массивом с одним единственным элементом.

Этот элемент среди прочих свойств имеет требуемый `attr`, который в свою очередь является ассоциативным массивом с единственным элементом (ключ `title` => значение `Значение поля`)

Следовательно, для того, чтобы получить искомое значение, надо сделать так:

```
$value = $ret[0]->attr['title']
```